# where does mantisBT install on a unix server

Tags: unix, mantis

This may seem a very stupid question, but if you go through the installation of mantisBT on a UNIX server, which directory does it install into?  I cannot find any of the files.

I foolishly thought that as the path was `http://myWebServerHere/mantis/login_page.php`, that if I went to the root of my web server (/var/www) i would then see a directory called mantis, with login_page.php in it. But I don't.

In that directory I see several other files that I can load by using the server url and the file name, but nothing else.

BTW How is it even possible for mantis to be loading in my browser if it isn't under www?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is it even possible for mantis to be loading in my browser if it isn't under www?

/var/www is just a directory, your web server can be configured to look for files in lots of locations. How depends on the web server.

Answer (score -1):

A colleague told me about 'locate', so I was able to find it.

'find' is useless, as you have to basically already know where it is to get close enough to see it. Otherwise if you use 'find' from root most of the resulting lines (usually with what you are looking for in it) disappears off the top of the terminal window, beyond where you can scroll back to.

Still don't know why things can be in more than one www directory and show up online.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and learn more about things before calling them useless. Piping the output of find or any other command through `more` or `less` will give you infinite scrolling (and lots of other features). Use it like this `find / -name foo.php | less`

Comment: the simplest functions and output should need the simplest commands.  if you have to put in a long string of commands to get a simple output (only the matches), it's a bad design.  complex output should expect complex input.